# Boolean does not control while loop for me

Tags: python, while-loop, sigkill

All of this code does not get affected by a SIGKILL command and my while loop continues no matter what condition
Code:

```
if Play == False:
  signal.SIGKILL(0)
if gameplayint == "N":
  print("What are you doing here then?")
  Play == False
if gameplayint == "Y":
  Play == True
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print("We will start now.")
#Start the game.
  print("")
#Actual gameplay block of code
#game start
while Play == True: 
  pcNum = random.randint(1,19)
  anotherNum = True
  total = 0
  
  while anotherNum == True:
    playerNum = random.randint(1,10)
    total = total + playerNum
    print("")
    print("Your number is ", str(playerNum) + ".")
    print("You have " + str(total) + " in total.")
    print("")
    again = input("Roll another number? <Y or N> ")
    print("")
    if again == "Y":
      anotherNum = True
    else:
      anotherNum = False
      break
  #game finished now
print("Computer got", pcNum)
print("You got", total)
#checking for winner
while anotherNum == False:
  if (total <= 13) and (total > pcNum): 
    print("You,", name, "have won!")
  elif (pcNum <= 13) and (pcNum > total):
    print("The computer has bested you,", name + "!")
  else:
    if (total == pcNum) and (total <= 13):
      print("Draw...")
    elif (pcNum > 13) and (total <= 13):
      print("You,", name + " have won!")
    else:
      print("Both of you have lost. Wow...")
again = input("Try again? <Y or N>")
if again == "Y":
  Play = True
else:
  Play = False
  print("Goodbye now.")
```

Output:

```
What's your name? Y
Very well then Y, do you want to play 13? <Y or N> N
What are you doing here then?

Your number is  3.
You have 3 in total.
```

The issue here is that despite N being outputted on the gameplayint variable, the while loop still continues instead of stopping the output entirely.

Comment: Looks like you are not assigning but rather comparing in all `if` clauses. `Play == False` should be `Play = False`

Comment: line 5 and 7, use single `=` for assigning